# Copy and modify html index file when building with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

My current structure of files goes like this

```
root/
  prod/
    index.html
    prod.js 
  webpack.config.js
  index.html
  bundle.js
  ...
```

`bundle.js` and `prod.js` generated from different webpack builds (separate commands)

`root/prod/index.html` file

```html
<script src="./prod.js">

rest of the html tags
```

`root/index.html` file

```html
<script src="./bundle.js">

rest of the html tags
```

what i need to do is everytime i run the prod build (builds files under the prod folder) is to copy the `root/index.html` to `root/prod/index.html` but modify

this line `<script src="./bundle.js">`

to this `<script src="./prod.js">`

i currently using the `copy-webpack-plug` in but this does not have an option to modify a file when coping

There is any way to achieve this kind of behavior instead of changing `root/prod/index.html` manually  every time (i mean replacing the script tag src attribute)?

my current webpack build looks like this

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs');
gracefulFs.gracefulify(fs);
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const entryPath = './entry-webpack.js';
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;


module.exports = (env) => {
  console.log('NODE_ENV: ', env.NODE_ENV);
  const ENV = env.NODE_ENV;
  let plugins = [];
  let enviroment;
  let bundleName;
  let exportPath;
  if (ENV === 'prod') {
    enviroment = 'production';
    plugins = [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({include: /\.min\.js$/}),
      new CopyPlugin([
        { from: 'index.html', to: './prod/index.html' }
      ])
    ];
    bundleName = 'prod';
    exportPath = './prod/[name].js';
  } else {
    enviroment = 'development';
    bundleName = 'bundle';
    exportPath = './[name].js';
  }

  return {
    context: path.join(__dirname, ''),
    mode: enviroment,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins,
    entry: {
      [bundleName]: entryPath,
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: exportPath,
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Anyway, you can use a temples library. For example Handlebar.js

Comment: Maybe this package will help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-replace-webpack-plugin

Comment: updated with my current configuration

Comment: @gugateider this looks helpfull, will this plug in change the original html.index under root folder? because i want to keep this untouched

Comment: If that is already being compiled by your build settings it should work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution but a workaround using `webpack-shell-plugin`

adding this to webpack plugins (executes anything pre and after build)

```
new WebpackShellPlugin(
  {
    onBuildStart:['echo "---Webpack Start---"'],
    onBuildEnd:['node replace-script']
  })
```

plus `replace-script.js` script

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./docs/index.html', 'utf8', (err, data) =>
    err ? console.log("ERROR" + err)
        : fs.writeFile(
            './docs/index.html',
            data.replace(`<script src="bundle.js">`, `<script src="prod.js"></script>`),
            'utf8',
            (err) =>
                err ? console.log("ERROR" + err)
                    : console.log("SUCCESS")
        )
);
```

a better solution without the need to add a new script would be much appreciated